# Troubleshoot docker connectivity to external network

Tags: ubuntu, networking, docker

> This was a **DNS server issue** -- the default server 8.8.8.8 (as pre-configured in Docker in Ubuntu) could be pinged but not reached via `nslookup`.

I'm having trouble to connect to the internet from a container on my local installation.

### My system

#### `ifconfig` looks fine

```
$ docker run -ti twelly/ifconfigme ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f2:bd:a6:53:6f:5f  
          inet addr:172.17.0.35  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f0bd:a6ff:fe53:6f5f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:2 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:90 (90.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

#### I can `ping 8.8.8.8`

```
$ docker run -ti twelly/ifconfigme ping -c 3 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=33.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=33.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=33.5 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 33.525/33.597/33.650/0.218 ms
```

#### `ping` exits with failure after a timeout

```
$ time docker run -ti twelly/ifconfigme ping -c 3 google.com
ping: unknown host google.com

real    0m40.267s
user    0m0.014s
sys 0m0.012s
```

I have the same results with `debian:latest`, but I cannot test `ifconfig` because it's not installed there.

### New VM

The same setting works in a new Ubuntu Utopic 14.10 virtual machine.

#### `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/utopic/current/utopic-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box"

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "apt-get install -y docker.io && adduser vagrant docker"
end
```

#### Command

```
$ vagrant up && vagrant ssh -c "docker run -ti twelly/ifconfigme ping -c 3 google.com"
```

#### Question

What am I possibly doing wrong? How to troubleshoot this?

Comment: can you post a copy of your ```Dockerfile``` used to create the ifconfigme image? also what happens when you try ping google's dns ip address 8.8.8.8?

Comment: @booyaa: It's not specific to this particular image, the same fails with `debian:latest` which has a [public `Dockerfile`](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-debian/blob/8105df0412f86c08d11e86f7f6bab6160ff1e837/wheezy/Dockerfile) (not very helpful, though). I use this particular image in the example because it has `ifconfig` by default.

Comment: It could be either a general network failure, or just a DNS failure. So can you ping 8.8.8.8 from container?

Comment: @VitalyIsaev: Bingo, that one works.

Comment: @VitalyIsaev: But `docker run --dns=8.8.8.8` doesn't help either. How to solve this?

Comment: @krlmlr, very strange. Please show `/etc/resolv.conf` from container when you do `docker run --dns=8.8.8.8`

Comment: @VitalyIsaev: Found it. I can ping 8.8.8.8, but *not* use it as a name server. I assume it's firewall rules, but it's strange that *both* universities I tried this from have such a firewall rule. Everything works if I use the university's name server via `--dns=...`. Thanks for your help, I'll be glad to accept an answer of yours.

Comment: @krlmlr, I'm glad to help you) DNS always brings problem. Finally I had to deploy `SkyDNS+SkyDock` on my host in order to allow containers discover each other and some of our inner services...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74832/discussion-between-krlmlr-and-vitaly-isaev).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to specify that you don't want that the connectivity to be managed by the container. Use `--net=host` in your run command.

Comment: Are there any downsides to using `--net=host`?

Comment: I am not sure about it.

Several people are facing the same problem as us, see that [link](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13914).

However, it doesn't look like it will downsize your connection if you use it, [see that link](http://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/).

Comment: As the document says: "The host network adds a container on the hosts network stack. You’ll find the network configuration inside the container is identical to the host."

It will just share the same network configuration as the container has. I don't know if it may be a security issue.